# Configuring New relic in Spring boot with insight key

Tags: spring-boot, newrelic, micrometer

In my springboot application, I have put following in my application.properties:

> management.metrics.export.newrelic.api-key=MY_INSIGHT_KEY
>
> management.metrics.export.newrelic.account-id=MY_NEWRELIC_ACCOUNT_ID

And in pom file, I have inserted micrometer-newrelic dependency as:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-new-relic</artifactId>
        <version>${micrometer.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

But I don't see any metrics at insight [site](https://insights.newrelic.com).

What am I missing in configuration?

Edit:

[This link](https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/new-relic) documents configuring micrometer for new relic in spring boot 2.

It asks to implement NewRelicConfig interface and create NewRelicMeterRegistry with it.

But where do I need to place this code in springboot 2 application.

Comment: Asked on github too:https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer-samples-spring-boot/issues/5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to your (correct) Spring configuration you must also add:

```
management.metrics.export.newrelic.enabled=true
```

You also need a copy of the New Relic agent newrelic.jar and a newrelic.yml configuration file with your licence key in it.

To get it, log in to your New Relic account and go to Insights. The menu at the top of the page has a head and shoulders image and your account name on the right-hand side. Click that and in the drop down menu click Account Settings.

On the right hand side of the Account Settings page there is a section titled 'Update your New Relic agent'. Click on the version number for the Java SE agent to download the zip file. Unpack the zip file and newrelic.jar and the template newrelic.yml are the files you need, they are in the top level directory of the extract.

Edit newrelic.yml and find this line:

```
license_key: '<%= license_key %>'.
```

Remove <%= license_key %> and replace it with the licence key shown on the Account Settings page (its just above the section titled 'Update your New Relic agent'). The line should now look something like this (this isn't a real licence key BTW):

```
license_key: 'aab23456cf2a09'
```

Now when you run your application you will need to add the following JVM arguments:

```
-javaagent:newrelic.jar 
-Dnewrelic.config.file=newrelic.yml 
-Dnewrelic.environment=DEV
```

If newrelic.jar or newrelic.yml are not in your working directory, adjust the paths in these arguments appropriately. If you don't provide newrelic.jar then a stub implementation of the API is used instead and nothing gets sent to New Relic.

If you want confirmation from your app that it is sending metrics to New Relic then turn on logging in your application properties file:

```
logging.level.io.micrometer.newrelic=TRACE
```

This will show details of what is being sent to New Relic.

Comment: The New Relic agent jar is totally orthogonal to Micrometer support. It's fine if you include both the agent _and_ Micrometer configuration, but it isn't necessary.

Comment: So the jar and newrelic.yml file are not needed if micrometer is setup in the application?

Answer (score 1):

Those directions assume you are not using Spring Boot. The Spring Boot reference manual indicates how to properly configure New Relic: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-metrics-export-newrelic

Comment: For some reason if I do not include jar/agent I do not see any logs in New Relic side.

Comment: How to integrate new relic to spring boot using micrometer and not java agent?